# Concordancia de tiempos aplicada en oraciones condicionales

Tags: condicional, concordancia-verbal

La mayoría de los artículos que leo dicen que, después de una proposición subordinada condicional del tipo "si + presente del indicativo", hay que conjugar el verbo de la proposición principal ya sea en el presente de indicativo, el imperativo o el futuro del indicativo.

> Si tengo hambre, como.

> Si tienes dinero, cómpratelo.

> Si puedo ayudarte, lo haré.

Pero a pesar de que el verbo de la proposición principal es conjugado en el condicional simple, la siguiente oración no se me antoja incorrecta:

> Si quieres progresar, deberías practicar más a menudo.

¿Os resulta correcta dicha oración?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La oración:

> Si quieres progresar, deberías practicar más a menudo.

es correcta. Combina una condición real (el hecho de que quieres progresar) con una recomendación (creo que deberías practicar más). La concordancia entre tiempos en las oraciones condicionales no se limita a las tres combinaciones canónicas (presente-futuro / pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo-condicional / pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo-condicional perfecto) sino que presenta una variedad mucho más amplia que, a mi entender, puede deberse a por lo menos dos factores que encuentro relacionados entre sí:

1. La combinación de condiciones (prótasis) y resultados (apódosis) en distintos modos verbales.
2. La coexistencia de distintas funciones o de diferentes planos del lenguaje.

Algunos ejemplos:

a- Si querías progresar, deberías haber practicado más.

b- Si quieres progresar, hubieras practicado más.

c- Si quieres progresar, podría ayudarte.

En el ejemplo (a), la prótasis es un caso de función referencial (si es un hecho que querías progresar) mientras que la apódosis, en modo potencial, refleja el sentimiento del hablante (función expresiva), que reprocha al interlocutor no haber practicado lo suficiente.

El ejemplo (b) es similar, sólo que la prótasis está en presente (si es verdad que quieres progresar). La apódosis también expresa reproche.

En el ejemplo (c), la función del lenguaje en la apódosis parece apelativa o conativa, como una invitación indirecta a que el interlocutor acepte la ayuda del hablante.

En general, los tiempos de los tipos canónicos muestran relaciones más directas entre condición y resultado:

- Si progresas, triunfarás. (progreso -> triunfo)
- Si progresaras, estaría muy feliz. (tu progreso -> mi felicidad)
- Si hubieras progresado, habrías ganado mucho dinero. (tu hipotético progreso -> tu hipotético éxito económico)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta!